# load multiple attributers using load() Magento

Tags: product, attributes, database, multiple

I am using this code but it's not working with multiple parameter. I want only use load() function in magento. You can see below code any please help me.

```
$attributes = array('entity_id'=> 1684, 'advertise_id'=> 283);
$model= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($attributes);
```

Thanks for support in advance.

Comment: Why multiple parameters? You only need one for load function, that is your entity_id.

Comment: when i use Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); at that time "advertise_id" attribute not come and when i use load() than coming this attribute. so i am using multiple parameter with load(). what can i do get "advertise_id" come using getCollection();

Comment: @KartikAsodariya you can get advertise_id attribute value by load product  just using an id.

Comment: I know if i am using single product id. Right ? but still i am using multiple products id so it's not possible and this collection i am using block file

Comment: You can't get multiple products by load() method. it use for load single product only.

Comment: Okay so can i solve my problem can you please suggest me ?

Comment: In which page you are getting product collections? list page?

Comment: No, I am using custom grid and also doing pagination and searching functionality

Answer (score 2):

Based upon your comments, I gather you are trying to iterate over a collection of products IDs and trying to get the 'advertise_id' column. In that case, I'd strongly suggest against `load` method. Using of `load` inside a loop will be like killing your mySql with your own hands.

You should try with this code :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('advertise_id')
    ->addIdFilter($idArray);

foreach($collection as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value->getData('advertise_id'));
}
```

Where `$idArray` is simply the array containing all the IDs of products you are trying to access.

Comment: when i use Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); at that time "advertise_id" attribute not come and when i use load() than coming this attribute. so i am using multiple parameter with load().

Comment: You have to use `addAttributeToSelect` for that attribute to come in the collection. If it is still not coming, then check if you are using flat catalog. In that case. open up the attribute and make it available in product listing and then re-index the flat catalog product index.

Answer (score 1):

Hello if you want to load your model with out using primary key column you can use

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load("your data",'column_name');
```

Comment: Thanks for giving example but it's not my requirement. I know about how to define single value in load(). can you please help me with this parameter
$attributes = array('entity_id'=> 1684, 'advertise_id'=> 283);

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in product page, you should load product by id.

**$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)**

From this product object, you can get your custom attribute value

**$_product->getAdvertiseId();**

Comment: I know this is working. How many times i told i want multiple products ids using this functionality like load(). but you answer only one parameter

Answer (score 0):

you have to load through a collection:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
  ->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', 1684)
  ->addAttributeToFilter('advertise_id', 283)
  ->setPage(1, 1)
  ->getFirstItem();

if ($product->getId()) {
  ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

To solve the problem of `advertise_id` attribute not belonging to flat table, try this snippet:

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
  ->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'advertise_id');

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
  ->getCollection();

$productCollection
  ->getSelect()
  ->join(
    array('attributeTable' => $attribute->getBackend()->getTable()), 
    'e.entity_id = attributeTable.entity_id', 
    array('advertise_id' => 'attributeTable.value')
  )
  ->where("attributeTable.attribute_id = ?", $attribute->getAttributeId())
  ->where("attributeTable.value = ?", 283)
;  

$product = productCollection
  ->addIdFilter(1684)
  ->setPage(1, 1)
  ->getFirstItem();

if ($product->getId()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: when i use Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); at that time "advertise_id" attribute not come and when i use load() than coming this attribute. so i am using multiple parameter with load().

Comment: after the `getCollection()` call try adding `->addAttributeToSelect('advertise_id')`

Comment: I am using ->addAttributeToSelect('*') but still not coming "advertise_id" attribute

Comment: Oh that probably means you have flat catalog enabled and advertise_id is not in flat table; in that case you have 2 options: add that attribute in product listing by editing attribute in the Admin Panel or perform a programmatic join of the attribute in the collection. I'm not able now to provide an example being on my mobile device but you should find examples even here on Stack Exchange

Comment: Hi @KartikAsodariya did you try the snippet I put in the EDIT section of my answer? Did it work?